# Java Parse String in Class Instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

i want parse a String into a Class Instance.
My Data come from a .csv.

Code:

```
@Override
public List<Strasse> getByStadtId(Stadt stadtId){
    return repo.findByStadtId(stadtId);
}

@Override
public void saveStrassenData() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/csv/strassen.csv"));
        while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] data=line.split(",");
            Strasse strasse = new Strasse();
            Stadt stadt = new Stadt();
            strasse.setId(Long.parseLong(data[0]));
            strasse.setName(data[1]);
            strasse.setVerwaltungsKuerzel(data[2]);
            strasse.setStadt(data[3]);
            repo.save(strasse);
        } 
    
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In Picture 1 you can see my error.

[Picture of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swMyA.png)

My Class is in the pictures:

[image]

The .csv

[image]

Comment: create a function that parses the string and convert it to the object that you want. Are you passing json as a string?

Comment: Have you tried `String.valueOf()` ?

Comment: You're calling `setStadt()` which takes an instance of `Stadt` but you are passing in `data[3]` which is a `String`.

Comment: Yes. I want to write from my .csv in to a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setStadt` doesn't take a String. You need to create an instance of Stadt and then you could set it's `id`.

Something like that:

```
Stadt stadt = new Stadt();
stadt.setId(data[3]);
strasse.setStadt(stadt);
```

Comment: I get this error -> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"

Comment: Thank you, i found the mistake :) I had a misspelling in the .csv ^^

Answer (score 0):

The handling of Stadt and validation of Strasse is missing.

```
@Override
public void saveStrassenData() {
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1; // Or UTF_8.
    try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/csv/strassen.csv");
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in, charset))) {
        while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data=line.split(",\\s*");
            Strasse straße = new Strasse();

            long stadtId = Long.parseLong(data[3]);
            Stadt stadt = new Stadt(); // repo.getStadtById(stadtId);
            stadt.setId(stadtId);      //

            straße.setId(Long.parseLong(data[0]));
            straße.setName(data[1]);
            straße.setVerwaltungsKuerzel(data[2]);
            straße.setStadt(stadt;     // <--
            repo.save(straße);
        } 
    
    }
    catch (IOException e) { // Better method with throws IOException.
        e.printStackTrace(); // Log.
    }
}
```

Also the old utility class FileReader uses the default charset, for a German Windows Cp-1252, a superset of ISO-8859-1. For a server likely UTF-8. Better state the charset explicitly, especially when you provide it yourself as read-only resource.